# How to convert `Wrapped` to `CVarArg`?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have an app that deals with a lot of optional data that needs displayed in the form

```
<Latest value formatted (units)> || "never updated"
```

so obviously my code is full of things like:

```
var pressureString: String {
    (self.lastData != nil) ?
        String(format: "%.2f kPa", self.lastData!.pressure.doubleValue)
        :
        Constants.neverUpdated // NSLocalizedString
}
```

So I decided to try and tidy this up with this:

```
var pressureString: String {
    (self.lastData?.pressure.doubleValue).format("%.2f kPa", or: Constants.neverUpdated)
}
```

and wrote `format` as:

```
extension Optional {
    func format(_ formatString: String, or: String) -> String {
        if let s = self {
            return String(format: formatString, s)
        } else {
            return or
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error "Argument type 'Wrapped' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'", and on looking up the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cvararg, I see

> Declaring conformance to the CVarArg protocol for types defined
>   outside the standard library is not supported.

... so is there *any* way to format a generic `Wrapped`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Swift 5***

You can write an extension like ->

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == CVarArg {

    func format(_ formatString: String, or: String) -> String {
        guard let self = self else { return or }
        return String(format: formatString, self)
    }
}
```

Comment: How foolish do I feel!?! :)